Can we invite users to the private beta?
Ok so as has been raised a couple of times, we're fairly niche as SE sites go and are, like many of the public beta sites, not generating StackOverflow quantities of content quite yet.
So obviously this is not so good. However, we have some awesome technical minds here. It strikes me that the likes of Mr Pornin may well know other cryptographers who would like to or be willing to take part in our private beta. 
My question is, assuming a given dedicated user of this private beta, we'll call him Mr D, wishes to invite his friend Mr F, can he? Or are we stuck with the users who committed to the private beta and have elected to sign up?
I realise this might defeat the point of the Area 51 process to some extent, but I feel it is worth asking the question.

For now it looks like we don't need more experts, but more non-experts which whish to ask questions :-)

@Paulo very true...!

Generally speaking, a private beta is limited to the committers for a brief site-building exercise. There's no invite-a-user interface, but if you have someone specific in mind, send me an email and I will see what I can do.
